# extract some part of a list of strings and set them in a list without any repetition

Tags: linux, bash, list

I have a list of file names I have tried to extract the index between `sil.` and `.asc` and put them in a list while I do not to have the repetition of indexes in my list. The following is some part of the list of my files.

```
ellip5.0.apo.3.sil.16.asc
ellip5.0.apo.3.sil.7.asc
ellip5.0.apo.3.sil.8.asc
ellip5.0.apo.4.sil.3.asc
ellip5.0.apo.4.sil.14.asc
ellip5.0.apo.4.sil.5.asc
ellip5.0.apo.4.sil.6.asc
ellip5.0.apo.4.sil.7.asc
ellip5.0.apo.4.sil.8.asc
ellip5.0.apo.5.sil.3.asc
ellip5.0.apo.5.sil.14.asc
ellip5.0.apo.5.sil.5.asc
ellip5.0.apo.5.sil.6.asc
ellip5.0.apo.5.sil.7.asc
ellip5.0.apo.5.sil.8.asc
ellip5.0.apo.6.sil.3.asc
ellip5.0.apo.6.sil.4.asc
ellip5.0.apo.6.sil.5.asc
ellip5.0.apo.6.sil.16.asc
ellip5.0.apo.6.sil.7.asc
ellip5.0.apo.6.sil.8.asc
ellip5.0.apo.7.sil.13.asc
ellip5.0.apo.7.sil.4.asc
ellip5.0.apo.7.sil.5.asc
```

The following code is my attempt to make the list but it doesn't work

```
args=()
containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}
for MYVAR in  "ellip*.asc"
j=0
for i in $(ls ellip*.asc)
do
  INDEX=`echo $i | grep -oE 'sil.[^/]+.asc' | cut -c5- | rev | cut -c5- | rev`
  listcontains INDEX "${args[@]}" 
  if [ $? == 1 ];then
        args[j]=$INDEX
        j=$(($j + 1))
        echo $INDEX
   fi
done
echo ${args[@]}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated..
My expected list would be :

```
16 7 8 3 14 5 6 16 4 13
```

and preferably a sorted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script in BASH 4:

```
# declare an associative array
declare -A arr

for f in ellip*.asc; do
    f="${f/#*sil.}"
    f="${f%.asc}"
    arr["$f"]=1
done

# print sorted index values
printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}" | sort -n
3
4
5
6
7
8
13
14
16
```

---

In **older BASH where associative array is not supported** use:

```
declare -a arr

for f in ellip*.asc; do
    f="${f/#*sil.}"
    f="${f%.asc}"
    arr+=("$f")
done

sort -un <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")
```

**Output:**

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
13
14
16
```

Comment: can you please explain how `f="${f/#*sil.}"` and `f="${f%.asc}"` help to split the string? Because when I try to get the number between `apo.` and `.sil` it doesn't return the right values.

Comment: `f="${f/#*sil.}"` is removing everything from start to `sil.` and `f="${f%.asc}"` is removing `.asc` in the end. I have created al the files exactly as your question and both the scripts worked fine in my testing.

Comment: I also want to get the number between `apo.` and `.sil` but it doesn't work with changing a bit your solution.  I am wondering why did you set `arr["$f"]=1`?

Comment: `arr["$f"]=1` is storing those indexes in an array `arr`. Can you run `unset arr; declare -A arr; for f in ellip*.asc; do echo "<$f>"; f="${f/#*sil.}"; f="${f%.asc}"; arr["$f"]=1; done` and tell me what you see on your terminal. I see `<ellip5.0.apo.3.sil.16.asc>`, `<ellip5.0.apo.3.sil.7.asc>` etc in different lines.

Comment: it does return what you wrote plus when I run echo `${arr[@]}`, it returns wrong answer.

Comment: It must be `echo "${!arr[@]}"` not `echo ${arr[@]}` you can see my first example.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like

```
ls ellip*.asc | cut -f 6 -d . | sort -nu
```

The `cut` program does just what you want here, selecting the 6th field as separated by delimiters of `.` .

Comment: How could I put the output of your answer in an array?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone else -- I don't know about shell arrays!

Comment: Also I think requirement says **extract the index between sil. and .asc** It may not be safer to assume 6th field is index. Besides parsing `ls` output can be error prone.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think it will work like this `arr=( $( ls ellip*.asc | cut -f 6 -d . | sort -nu))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't worry about using some utilities (which you probably don't, as you already have `grep`, `cut` and `rev` in your example), then you can do this in a oneliner:

```
arr=($(sed 's/ /\n/g' <<< $(echo *.sil.*.asc) |cut -d. -f6 |sort -n |uniq))
```

This will first get your file list (note that you need `echo` to input your file list to `sed`, since pathnames are not expanded after `<<<`), break it into lines, select the 6th field with delimiters set to `.`, then choose a uniqe value from each (also note that `uniq` needs a sorted list as input). This list is then assigned to an array.

Also also note that in your example you have:

```
...
for i in $(ls ellip*.asc)
do
...
```

Here you parse the output of `ls`, which you should generally avoid, [see here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Specifically in this case it would probably be safe, as your filenames have a fixed format.